# WikiExtractor Warning Template errors in article

Tags: python, wikipedia, dump

I wanted to transform Wikipedia database dump in XML into plain text format. So I used WikiExtractor function from this page http://attardi.github.io/wikiextractor/. However when I run the command line on my terminal:
 WikiExtractor.py enwiki20160113pagesarticles.xml 
However, warning messages like "WARNING: Template errors in article 'Old Town San Diego State Historic Park' (1158971): title(0) recursion(116, 0, 0)" appear each 10 seconds. Can you please tell me what this message means? Are these warning messages serious? 
Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In wikiextractor github someone reported a similar issue... the answer is: "The warnings are normal, due to malformed templates." See more details: https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor/issues/33